# Eslint plugin for mobx that warns if you are using the store without an observer

Tags: eslint, mobx, mobx-react

Does it exist the eslint plugin that warns if i use mobx actions inside a component that is not wrapped in observer HOC:

```
const Comp1 = () => {
 const store = useContext(rootContext)
 return (
   number: {store.number}
   <button onClick={() => store.incByOne()}>increase number by 1</button>
 )
}

export default Comp1  // warn on console
export default observer(Comp1) // fine
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is none, because it won't be possible for eslint to actually understand that you are using some sort of `observable` value. And `observer` could be defined in different ways too, not wrapping component inside one does not mean that you are not doing it somewhere else.

There is a [configuration option](https://mobx.js.org/configuration.html#observablerequiresreaction-boolean) for MobX though:

```
configure({ observableRequiresReaction: true })
```

> Warns about any unobserved observable access. Use this if you want to check whether you are using observables without a "MobX context". This is a great way to find any missing observer wrappers, for example in React components. But it will find missing actions as well.